# How to find the smallest sector of a circle that covers a polygon?

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry, polygon, nettopologysuite

Given the circle C: (O, r) and the polygon P, how can I find the smallest sector of C that covers P?

[image]

Assume that the radius of the circle is large enough, so the main problem is to find the initial and final angles of the sector.

I tried to draw rays from center of circle toward each of angles of the polygon and check if the ray overlaps the polygon. But there might be more than two rays that only touch the polygon. I can not rely on the selection of unique rays based on their direction angle, due to double precision. So finding min and max angles in the list of touched rays is useless. Beside that, I have problem with choosing either of sectors created by two terminal angles, since initial angle can be greater than final angle when computed by `atan2`.
[image]

So what is the proper way to find such a sector?

**Edit:**
Three example polygons (in WKT format):

```
POLYGON((52.87404 30.85613, 42.55699 28.46292, 41.54373 24.319989, 53.57623 21.300564, 62.94891 28.46292, 49.39652 27.550071, 52.87404 30.85613))
POLYGON((52.94294 30.920592, 42.55699 28.46292, 43.61965 35.545578, 55.85037 34.862696, 59.12524 36.621547, 47.68664 39.877048, 35.69973 36.198265, 37.30512 29.196711, 31.09762 28.46292, 41.54373 24.319989, 53.57623 21.300564, 62.94891 28.46292, 49.39652 27.550071, 52.94294 30.920592))
POLYGON((52.94294 30.920592, 42.55699 28.46292, 43.61965 35.545578, 52.45594 37.266299, 59.30560 29.196711, 64.12177 33.290489, 58.81733 36.554277, 47.68664 39.877048, 35.69973 36.198265, 37.30512 29.196711, 31.09762 28.46292, 41.54373 24.319989, 53.57623 21.300564, 62.94891 28.46292, 49.39652 27.550071, 52.94294 30.920592))
```

Center and radius of circle for all examples:

```
O: (45, 30)
r: 25
```

Comment: Love the pictures.  Can you post some example data to work with?  A center point of the circle with a radius, as well as a list of points defining one or more of those polygons.  Also, you've posted on the weekend, during a three day holiday weekend for many, so don't expect too many hits on this until possibly Tuesday...

Comment: @Idle_Mind, thanks for your kind words. Added the examples.

Answer (score 2):

For starters we can handle your data as point cloud (polygon vertexes) `p[i]` and some circle defined by center `p0` and radius `r`. If your point cloud is entirely inside circle you can ignore the radius.

We can exploit `atan2` however to avoid problems with crossing and sector selection we do not enlarge min/max bounds as usual for standard cartesian BBOX computation instead:

1. **compute `atan2` angle for each point and remember it in array `a[]`**
2. **sort `a[]`**
3. **find biggest distance between consequent angles in `a[]`**

   Do not forget that angle difference can be `|Pi|` tops so if it is more you need to `+/- 2*PI`. Also handle `a[]` as cyclic buffer.

**This is my simple C++/VCL attempt:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
float p0[]={52.87404,30.856130,42.55699,28.46292,41.54373,24.319989,53.57623,21.300564,62.94891,28.46292,49.39652,27.550071,52.87404,30.85613,};
float p1[]={52.94294,30.920592,42.55699,28.46292,43.61965,35.545578,55.85037,34.862696,59.12524,36.621547,47.68664,39.877048,35.69973,36.198265,37.30512,29.196711,31.09762,28.46292,41.54373,24.319989,53.57623,21.300564,62.94891,28.46292,49.39652,27.550071,52.94294,30.920592,};
float p2[]={52.94294,30.920592,42.55699,28.46292,43.61965,35.545578,52.45594,37.266299,59.30560,29.196711,64.12177,33.290489,58.81733,36.554277,47.68664,39.877048,35.69973,36.198265,37.30512,29.196711,31.09762,28.46292,41.54373,24.319989,53.57623,21.300564,62.94891,28.46292,49.39652,27.550071,52.94294,30.920592,};
float x0=45.0,y0=30.0,R=25.0;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> void sort_asc_bubble(T *a,int n)
    {
    int i,e; T a0,a1;
    for (e=1;e;n--)                                     // loop until no swap occurs
     for (e=0,a0=a[0],a1=a[1],i=1;i<n;a0=a1,i++,a1=a[i])// proces unsorted part of array
      if (a0>a1)                                        // condition if swap needed
      { a[i-1]=a1; a[i]=a0; a1=a0; e=1; }               // swap and allow to process array again
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void get_sector(float x0,float y0,float r,float *p,int n,float &a0,float &a1)
    {
    // x0,y0    circle center
    // r        circle radius
    // p[n]     polyline vertexes
    // a0,a1    output angle range a0<=a1
    int i,j,m=n>>1;
    float x,y,*a;
    a=new float[m];
    // process points and compute angles
    for (j=0,i=0;i<n;j++)
        {
        x=p[i]-x0; i++;
        y=p[i]-y0; i++;
        a[j]=atan2(y,x);
        }
    // sort by angle
    sort_asc_bubble(a,m);
    // get max distance
    a0=a[m-1]; a1=a[0]; x=a1-a0;
    while (x<-M_PI) x+=2.0*M_PI;
    while (x>+M_PI) x-=2.0*M_PI;
    if (x<0.0) x=-x;
    for (j=1;j<m;j++)
        {
        y=a[j]-a[j-1];
        while (y<-M_PI) y+=2.0*M_PI;
        while (y>+M_PI) y-=2.0*M_PI;
        if (y<0.0) y=-y;
        if (y>x){ a0=a[j-1]; a1=a[j]; x=y; }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TMain::draw()
    {
    int i,n;
    float x,y,r,*p,a0=0.0,a1=0.0;
    float ax,ay,bx,by;
    float zoom=7.0;
    p=p0; n=sizeof(p0)/sizeof(p0[0]);
//  p=p1; n=sizeof(p1)/sizeof(p1[0]);
//  p=p2; n=sizeof(p2)/sizeof(p2[0]);

    get_sector(x0,y0,R,p,n,a0,a1);

    // clear buffer
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
    bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));

    // circle
    x=x0; y=y0; r=R;
    ax=x+R*cos(a0);
    ay=y+R*sin(a0);
    bx=x+R*cos(a1);
    by=y+R*sin(a1);
    x*=zoom; y*=zoom; r*=zoom;
    ax*=zoom; ay*=zoom;
    bx*=zoom; by*=zoom;
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlue;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=TColor(0x00101010);
    bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r);
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clAqua;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=TColor(0x00202020);
    bmp->Canvas->Pie(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r,ax,ay,bx,by);

    // PCL
    r=2.0;
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clAqua;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clAqua;
    for (i=0;i<n;)
        {
        x=p[i]; i++;
        y=p[i]; i++;
        x*=zoom; y*=zoom;
        bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x-r,y-r,x+r,y+r);
        }

    // render backbuffer
    Main->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can ignore the `void TMain::draw()` function its just example of usage and this is the preview:

[image: overview]

However as you have polygon (lines) to avoid wrong results You have two simple options:

1. **sample lines with more than just 2 points**

   this way the angular gap should be bigger than distances between points in the point cloud. So if you sample lines with enough points the result will be correct. However wrongly selected number of points per line will lead to wrong result in edge cases. On the other hand implementing this is just simple DDA interpolation added to current code.
2. **convert to handling angle intervals instead of angles `a[]`**

   so for each line compute angular interval `<a0,a1>` with predefined poygon winding rule (so CW or CCW but consistent). And instead of array `a[]` you would have ordered list of intervals where you would either insert new interval or merge with existing if overlap. This approach is safe but merging angular intervals is not that easy. If the input data is polyline (like yours) that means each next line start from the previous line endpoint so you can ignore the list of intervals and just enlarge the single one instead but still you need to handle the enlargement correctly which is not trivial.

**[Edit1] using the first approach the updated function look like this:**

```cpp
void get_sector_pol(float x0,float y0,float r,float *p,int n,float &a0,float &a1)
    {
    // x0,y0    circle center
    // r        circle radius
    // p[n]     point cloud
    // a0,a1    output angle range a0<=a1
    int i,j,k,N=10,m=(n>>1)*N;
    float ax,ay,bx,by,x,y,dx,dy,*a,_N=1.0/N;
    a=new float[m];
    // process points and compute angles
    bx=p[n-2]-x0; i++;
    by=p[n-1]-y0; i++;
    for (j=0,i=0;i<n;)
        {
        ax=bx; ay=by;
        bx=p[i]-x0; i++;
        by=p[i]-y0; i++;
        dx=_N*(bx-ax); x=ax;
        dy=_N*(by-ay); y=ay;
        for (k=0;k<N;k++,x+=dx,y+=dy,j++) a[j]=atan2(y,x);
        }
    // sort by angle
    sort_asc_bubble(a,m);
    // get max distance
    a0=a[m-1]; a1=a[0]; x=a1-a0;
    while (x<-M_PI) x+=2.0*M_PI;
    while (x>+M_PI) x-=2.0*M_PI;
    if (x<0.0) x=-x;
    for (j=1;j<m;j++)
        {
        y=a[j]-a[j-1];
        while (y<-M_PI) y+=2.0*M_PI;
        while (y>+M_PI) y-=2.0*M_PI;
        if (y<0.0) y=-y;
        if (y>x){ a0=a[j-1]; a1=a[j]; x=y; }
        }
    }
```

As you can see its almost the same just simple **DDA** is added to the first loop win `N` points per line. Here preview for the second polygon which fails with just point cloud approach:

[image: preview]

Comment: Were you able to put this amazing answer into use saastn?